# replace complex string with sed and single quote and reg x

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Hi everyone I've a problem about replace string with sed and regex.

I have a centent with duplicate text as below.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE xyz WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'NA': '3'
};

USE abc;

CREATE TABLE yyy (
.
.
.

) WITH

  caching='{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}' AND abcdefg....
```

I want to replace string with matching `caching='{.abcde..}` and `WITH replication = {..abc..}`

***don't care any text in bucket.

1. `caching='{..abc...}'`

Expected `caching='KEYS_ONLY'`

2. `WITH replication = {..abcdefg...}`

Expected `WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 }`

I've already tried command below but not success. it replaced and cut full text left only 1 line.

`sed -r "s/caching='\{(.|\n)*?\}'/caching='KEYS_ONLY'/g")`

`sed  -r "s/WITH replication = \{(.|\n)*?\}/WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 }/g")`

Can someone please suggest me. what should I do ?.

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear. Please consider rephrasing the question.

Comment: Can you post the expected output accompanying the example input? `sed` is good to parse single lines only. 
If you want to read multiple lines and match them, you need to use sed commands `N` or `n` and similar, or consider moving to `awk` and more aware utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use tr to replace \n to \f 
and then
please try to use [^\"]*? to match with non-greedy